# How to install kernel 3.9 in Debian Jessie from repos?

Tags: linux-kernel, debian

I was wondering if it is possible to install kernel 3.9 in Debian Jessie from repos. A brief check shows that there are only 2.6, 3.2 and 3.13 kernels in [repos](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-image-amd64) Compiling my own kernel is the last thing I want to do.

Btw I need kernel 3.9 in order to install Catalyst 3.12, because I am having serious problems with Catalyst 14.3 and I cannot install Catalyst 3.12 on kernels>3.9.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your first question, but this question is probably more appropriate at the superuser stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I will post it there.